# Figuring resistor wattage and value

Tags: batteries, resistors

I have a remote controlled airplane that I am putting LED lights on. The power supply is a lithium polymer battery that is rated at 22.2 volts and 4000 miliamps. I have an LED that is rated between 12-19 volts. How do I figure what size (wattage) and what value resistor to use. I have heard about Ohm's law and am familiar with the equation but obviously don't know how to apply it.

Comment: The voltage of the battery will vary a lot during discharge which means the brightness will vary too, unless a constant current driver is used. To calculate anything, the rated power (or current) of the LED is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a WAG and assume this LED you have is designed for automotive use on a "12VDC" source (typically more like 14V), so it already has a resistor in there. Be sure to verify this before hooking it up to a supply directly or you could damage the LED!

In that case, you will only need to add to the resistor(s) that are in there.

You can attach it to a power supply that outputs something like 14V (preferably a bench supply) and measure the current Im. Take that current Im, let's say it's 100mA, and calculate the value of the extra resistor:

Rs = \$\frac{22V-14V}{Im}\$   so for our example, it would be 80 ohms.

Pick a standard [E24 value](http://www.logwell.com/tech/components/resistor_values.html) that's the same or a bit higher (say 82 Ohms in this case).

Power will be \$\frac{(22V-14V)^2}{R}\$, so for our example 0.8W. Pick one that's a bit higher, say 1W or 2W.

Go to your favorite distributor and find a resistor with the required specs.

Answer (score 0):

You state that the LED has a voltage between 12-19 Volts. All of the LEDs that I have used have been rated at one specific voltage so I am not sure if you are mistaken with this voltage range rating? I think you should research this again.

The other piece of information that comes with the LED is its power rating which should be labelled on the package directly, for example for a LED of type X it could be given as 40 mW, 2V LED. Another indirect way of indicating the power rating of a LED is to give its rated current, for example for the same type X LED: 20mA, 2V LED. Power is then calculated via the formula: P = V x I, i.e. power= voltage x current = 20mA x 2V = 40 mW.

Anyways, either way you need to inspect the package that your led came in and look for a power rating (do a search on the internet with the LED's part number if you can't find it on the package).

Once you have the power rating, P, of your led substitute your values into the following equations to figure out: a. The current required by your LED. b. The size resistor to insert in series with your led and 22.2 V battery.

a. I = (P of LED)/(Voltage of led).
b. R = (Battery Voltage - led voltage)/I. Where I is the current solved for in the first equation.

Finally, run a wire from the battery to the anode of the LED (tail of the arrow), then from the other (cathode) side of the LED to the resistor and then from the other side of resistor back to the battery.

Answer (score 0):

(i suspect the 4000mA is not max output but the full capacity of the battery e.g. 4000mAh) ••• the apx./proposed resistor wattage P<sub>R</sub> = (1/0.3) · (0.8 · 22.2<sub>BATT</sub>V - √(12·19)LED<sub>V</sub>)·I<sub>LED</sub> ••• example: (30%)<sup>-1</sup>·(80% · 22.2 - 15.1)·1V·100*<sup>(see note!)</sup>mA = 3.33·**266**mW = 887mW =apx. 3×250mW **OR** 1×1W ••• R = U/R = 2.66V/100*mA = 0.0266kΩ = 26.6Ω ••• chk. 2.66V²/26.6Ω = **0.266**W that is required to double or triple or more to keep the resistor cool enough (for not melting the solder in worst case) ••• note: 100*mA is typical for some power LED-s (is quite a heavy load for the battery - and may disable your airplane to take off**<sup>(see note.2!)</sup>) you need to know **OR** determine it by applying 15V to LED and measuring it´s actual current consumption with ampere meter ••• note.2: it's better to use PULSED LED - requires a driver circuit - at (std.) 10% duty e.g. 10µs ON 9µs OFF =AVG.apx 10mA drain for battery instead of 100mA (which requires a filter to the rest of the circuit AND/OR to LED pulser circuit) -- nothing is easy if you want to make it reasonably right ...

Comment: This answer could be, at least visually, better if you would use the built-in equation editor

Comment: Some line breaks would already clear it up dramatically.